# How can I tell what's in my iCloud backup?

Tags: icloud, backup

I have an iPhone 5s running iOS8 and a first generation iPad running iOS5, both logged in to my iCloud account. I'll skip some details and jump to the fact that I deleted my latest iCloud backup both from my iPad and my iPhone, as well as my computer running iCloud for Windows. I did it from all 3 just to make sure the backup got deleted (it wasn't initially showing it deleted, so I did it from all 3).

I then turned off iCloud backup on both devices. Finally, I turned it back on on just my iPhone. Then I let it do a backup. For some reason, the backup size is much larger than it looks like it should be. See screenshot attached. The settings shown there are the same settings that were in place when it did the backup this morning.

Why is the backup size so large? It looks like it should only be about 3MB in size, based on what I have checked. Incidentally, 4.6GB is the same size as the backup I said I originally deleted before starting this process. Is there any way to tell what's making the backup so large?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a case of the numbers not updating in a timely manner. Have you tried setting it how you wanted, forcing a backup, and checking back in a small amount of time?